# react native's flex doesn't work when the "on-screen button" is turned on

Tags: android, react-native

Whenever I turn off my android phone's "on-screen default button" (picture1), react-native's "flex" works well. But whenever I turn on the phone's "on-screen default button" (picture 2), I can't see the bottom portion (in the picture "hey there!").

In this case, **I want to show "hey there!" at the bottom, even if I turn on the physical android button.**

Any suggestion?

Picture 1 -
[image: picture 1]

Picture 2 -
[image: Picture 2]

Here is my code snippet

```
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={{height: hp('100%'), backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
      <Text>hey there!</Text>
    </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in `SafeAreaView`like this:

```js
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ height: "95%", backgroundColor: "skyblue" }} />
      <Text>hey there!</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: Tried with SafeAreaView. Unfortunately, it didn't work. 
Is it because I was running a debugging version?!

Comment: @naimur978 No, debugging just makes it slower. I just edited the above answer. It should work fine now.